# Do the free indices referring to the same dimension have to be denoted by the same letter on both sides of an expression when using Einstein notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, tensors, index-notation

If there is an equation in vector form, ie:

$$y=Ax$$

I know that I can rewrite this using [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation):

$$y_i = A_{ij}x_j$$

I believe the above is valid. Would this:

$$y_i = A_{ji}x_i$$

be still valid though, and does this mean the same thing?

I think it would be reasonable if it was valid, since there are only one free index on both sides of the equation, so there is no ambiguity. I do not however see this in texts, so I think this is in fact invalid.

So, is $y_i = A_{ji}x_i$ a valid expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, free indices corresponding to equal quantities should use the same letter.

$y_i$ means the "$i$th entry of $y$". $A_{ji}x_i$, on the other hand, is the $j$th entry of the matrix product of $Ax$.  So, the equation $y_i = A_{ji}x_i$ amounts to saying that the $i$th entry of $y$ is equal to the $j$th entry of $Ax$ for arbitrary indices $i,j$.

This is different from saying that the $i$th entry of $y$ is equal to the $i$th entry of $Ax$ for arbitrary indices $i$, which is what is conventionally meant by the expression $y = Ax$.